# Get select tag's options by javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

HTML Code:

```
<select name="speed" style="width:100px">
    <option value="1" >1 RMB</option>
    <option value="2" >2 RMB</option>
    <option value="3" >3 RMB</option>
    <option value="4" >4 RMB</option>
    <option value="5" >5 RMB</option>
    <option value="6" >6 RMB</option>
    <option value="7" >7 RMB</option>
    <option value="8" >8 RMB</option>
    <option value="9" >9 RMB</option>
    <option value="10">10 RMB</option>
</select>
```

JS/jQuery Code:

```
$("select[name=speed] option").click(function(   
    alert('xxx');
    var uuid=$(this).attr('id');
    var speed=$(this).val();
    var url = "/dashboard/speed?uuid=" + uuid + "&speed=" + speed;
    alert('xxx');
));
```

I just want get the `id` and `value`. But there seems something to be going wrong. Could someone help me?

Comment: Don't just linkdump. Provide the relevant code in your question. Also check you browser's error console.

Comment: Well, it is *GOOD* to add an `id` in your `select` at first place...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `select` it should be the `change` event and the syntax near `function` was wrong. Corrected code:

```
$("select[name=speed]").change(function(){  
    var uuid=$(this).attr('id');
    var speed=$(this).val();
    var url = "/dashboard/speed?uuid=" + uuid + "&speed=" + speed;
    alert(url);
});
```

**[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wM653/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

Replace with this script

```
$("select[name=speed]").change('option',function(){   
    alert('xxx');
   var uuid=$(this).attr('id');
    var speed=$(this).val();
    var url = "/dashboard/speed?uuid=" + uuid + "&speed=" + speed;
    alert(url);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to execute code as parameters.

This will work

```
$("select[name=speed]").change(function(){
    alert('xxx');
    var uuid=$(this).attr('id');
    var speed=$(this).val();
    var url = "/dashboard/speed?uuid=" + uuid + "&speed=" + speed;
    alert(url);
});
```